# Procedure on how to auto download required PDF files in app,based on user response

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf

Hi stack overflow community,
I am new to android app development.I am working on an app for my college with inbuilt PDF reader API which is working pretty well,but the problem is i had to include all the PDF files in my assets folder itself so the app size is becoming more than 50 MB which is too bad and more over all the users of my app dosn't require all the PDF files.So what i want to do is,display a custom alert dialog window with check boxes where the user checks the required files and only that PDF files gets downloaded to may be the assets folder or in the app and can be opened using the inbuilt PDF reader.
What is the procedure i have to follow to implement this like where i have to upload all the PDF files and what procedure should i follow to download the checked files.If possible i don't want them to be downloaded separately so that the user can open them using secondary PDF viewer,I want then to be opened using the Inbuilt PDF viewer in my app itself.
Thank you and correct me if i mentioned any thing incorrectly..

Comment: `downloaded to may be the assets folder or in the app`. Impossible.

Comment: `I want then to be opened using the Inbuilt PDF viewer`. Download to app's internal private memory. Have a look at `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: `where i have to upload all the PDF files`. That is up to your choice. Some where from where they can be downloaded.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for your response.could you be a bit more specific i.e a step by step instruction like.First i would like to upload them to google drive or any other.Now how should i make the download request from with in the app on the user selection.Then how should i set the download location with in the app and mor over the inbuilt PDF viewer looks into assets folder  for the required files now how should i set it to the downloaded location.Thank you

Comment: You are asking too much. You should ask only one thing at a time and show the code that gives troubles. Uploading and downloading from google drive for example is pretty standard so you could find code for that with a bit of effort.

Comment: thanks for your help @greenapps will look into it and ask if i get struck anyway.!!